# Angular 4 Observable not working when building with CLI

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-cli, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I'm doing a service that takes an Http Obserbable response, and returns a different observable with escencial data, here is the code:

```
public get<T>(url: string): Observable<T> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        this.http.get<HttpResponse<T>>(url, {observe: 'response'}).subscribe(
          (response) => {
            if(response.ok)
               observer.next(response.body.data);
            else
               observer.error(response.statusText);
         },
        (error) => {
           observer.error(error);
        },
        () => {
           observer.complete()
         }
     );
   });
}
```

It's working just fine on a fresh CLI project when you run `ng serve`, but when run through `ng build` and an external server (ej: lite-server) it shows:

`ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAzmy.png)

I debugged entire app, and realize that error is on that function, any idea where is the problem?
here is the packages I used:

```
"@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
"@angular/common": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.9",
"@angular/forms": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/http": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/router": "^4.4.6",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"rxjs": "^5.5.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.14"
```

Comment: May I ask why you're wrapping the observable from the `http.get` call instead of using the `map` operator to modify your data?

Comment: The error mentions `mergeMap()`, can you show us where you call this `get ` method or where you're using `mergeMap`?

Comment: I agree with @cyrix. There's absolutely no need to overcomplicate things. `this.http.get(...)` already returns an `Observable` -- just pass it to the consumer of your function.